# How do I restrict users to only being able to choose certain drives?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there any standard way in C++ to limit a user to only select certain drives in an OpenFileDialog?

I've got a function that checks drives if they're flash drives, and only those are supposed to be selectable by the user. The Dialog does have a filter, but all I've seen it used with are file endings, and I'm not sure how I'd go about to limiting drives. 
Is there any possible way or will I have to restrict this myself in the program?

Comment: OpenFileDialog is not standard.

Comment: I think you should search in your "OpenFileDialog" library's reference.

Comment: This is mostly a bad-conditioned problem:

What the user can do on a system depends on what user rights it has its system.

Writing an application that doesn't allow the user to access a drive he can access in other ways, will simply make the user to find a way to circumvent your limit: it will save on a place, and than copy from outside your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can reject attempts to change to certain drives via `IFileDialogEvents::OnFolderChanging`, but that's about it. See [IFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)